# Eclipse using Android XML-RPC help

Tags: android, eclipse, xml-rpc

I know this is a noobish question, but I cannot get android-xmlrpc properly hooked into my android project in eclipse. The project website offers no advice and I have little experience developing with eclipse. Could someone please tell me the necessary steps to get the library properly into my android project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[android-xmlrpc](http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/) seems to be an Eclipse project already.

Try uncompressing it somewhere in your workspace. And then goto Eclipse menu: File -> Import... and then pick "Existing Projects into Workspace" and select the directory with the uncompressed version.

Assuming you already have the [Eclipse ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html), everything should look Ok.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was going to be something that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following mschonaker's approach, but I had problems with build paths after the import. Following this tutorial worked for me:

http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-build-php-xml-rpc-server-client-and-android-app